# Contiki Cooja not showing stats in collect view

Tags: iot, contiki

I cannot get the graphs and statistics of collect view example. I have run the simulation for many minutes, but when I go to tools and select collect view the nodes portion in the next window is empty and I have also selected start collect and send commands to nodes but no luck nothing shows up on the graphs :

[image: simulation picture click to view]

Answer (score -1):

For collect-view to work, it must be defined in project-conf.h. After calling collect-view in #define, the process in collect-view.c becomes active and the consumption packages sent by the nodes are visualized on cooja.

## battery consumption I added

APPS += serial-shell collect-view

After the assignment is made, the consumption values on the sender and client should be sent to the router. For a more detailed explanation, you can read this [link](https://yazilimdnyasi.wordpress.com/2019/10/19/collect-view-example-for-contiki-os/).